# CTRL+X+E in ZSH

Tags: bash, zsh

In BASH a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> opens `$EDITOR` and, on exit, BASH executes that command. When i run <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> in BASH, i do need to SAVE it before exit.

What is the equivalent in ZSH to BASH's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>?

What is ZSH's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is ZSH's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>?

we can figure that out using `bindkey`:

```bash
"^@" set-mark-command
"^A" beginning-of-line
"^B" backward-char
"^D" delete-char-or-list
"^E" end-of-line
"^F" forward-char
"^G" send-break
"^H" backward-delete-char
"^I" expand-or-complete
"^J" accept-line
"^K" kill-line
"^L" clear-screen
"^M" accept-line
"^N" down-line-or-history
"^O" accept-line-and-down-history
"^P" up-line-or-history
"^Q" push-line
"^R" history-incremental-search-backward
"^S" history-incremental-search-forward
"^T" transpose-chars
"^U" kill-whole-line
"^V" quoted-insert
"^W" backward-kill-word
"^X^B" vi-match-bracket
"^X^E" edit-command-line
"^X^F" vi-find-next-char
"^X^J" vi-join
"^X^K" kill-buffer
"^X^N" infer-next-history
"^X^O" overwrite-mode
"^X^U" undo
"^X^V" vi-cmd-mode
"^X^X" exchange-point-and-mark
"^X*" expand-word
"^X=" what-cursor-position
"^XG" list-expand
"^Xg" list-expand
"^Xr" history-incremental-search-backward
"^Xs" history-incremental-search-forward
"^Xu" undo
"^Y" yank
"^[^D" list-choices
"^[^G" send-break
"^[^H" backward-kill-word
"^[^I" self-insert-unmeta
"^[^J" self-insert-unmeta
"^[^L" clear-screen
"^[^M" self-insert-unmeta
"^[^_" copy-prev-word
"^[ " expand-history
"^[!" expand-history
"^[\"" quote-region
"^[\$" spell-word
"^['" quote-line
"^[-" neg-argument
"^[." insert-last-word
"^[0" digit-argument
"^[1" digit-argument
"^[2" digit-argument
"^[3" digit-argument
"^[4" digit-argument
"^[5" digit-argument
"^[6" digit-argument
"^[7" digit-argument
"^[8" digit-argument
"^[9" digit-argument
"^[<" beginning-of-buffer-or-history
"^[>" end-of-buffer-or-history
"^[?" which-command
"^[A" accept-and-hold
"^[B" backward-word
"^[C" capitalize-word
"^[D" kill-word
"^[F" forward-word
"^[G" get-line
"^[H" run-help
"^[L" down-case-word
"^[N" history-search-forward
"^[OA" up-line-or-beginning-search
"^[OB" down-line-or-beginning-search
"^[OC" forward-char
"^[OD" backward-char
"^[OF" end-of-line
"^[OH" beginning-of-line
"^[P" history-search-backward
"^[Q" push-line
"^[S" spell-word
"^[T" transpose-words
"^[U" up-case-word
"^[W" copy-region-as-kill
"^[[1;5C" forward-word
"^[[1;5D" backward-word
"^[[200~" bracketed-paste
"^[[3;5~" kill-word
"^[[3~" delete-char
"^[[5~" up-line-or-history
"^[[6~" down-line-or-history
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
"^[[B" down-line-or-history
"^[[C" forward-char
"^[[D" backward-char
"^[[Z" reverse-menu-complete
"^[_" insert-last-word
"^[a" accept-and-hold
"^[b" backward-word
"^[c" capitalize-word
"^[d" kill-word
"^[f" forward-word
"^[g" get-line
"^[h" run-help
"^[l" "ls^J"
"^[m" copy-prev-shell-word
"^[n" history-search-forward
"^[p" history-search-backward
"^[q" push-line
"^[s" spell-word
"^[t" transpose-words
"^[u" up-case-word
"^[w" kill-region
"^[x" execute-named-cmd
"^[y" yank-pop
"^[z" execute-last-named-cmd
"^[|" vi-goto-column
"^[^?" backward-kill-word
"^_" undo
" " magic-space
"!"-"~" self-insert
"^?" backward-delete-char
"\M-^@"-"\M-^?" self-insert
```

We find `"^[x" execute-named-cmd`. Aha! That doesn't tell us anything!

So, we go and read `man zshzle` (the man page for the zsh line editor), and find that `execute-named-cmd` can be used to execute any of the other commands outlined in that document. For example,

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>`describe-key-briefly`</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>

(you can use <kbd>tab</kbd> completion here!)

puts us into a mode where we can type in key combinations and get what commands they bind to. (for example, try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> here!)

> What is the equivalent in ZSH to BASH's <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>?

maybe `edit-command-line`? try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, that's what it's bound to in my shell, or try running it manually, via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd><kbd>`edit-command-line`</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Strange, there's no `edit-command-line` in my ZSH (5.8.1), nor in manpages.

Comment: Ok, i enabled it with this in zshrc: `utoload edit-command-line; zle -N edit-command-line`. Now need to know how to add a key.

Comment: DONE: `bindkey "^X^E" edit-command-line`